# C3 chart how to set format of json data to show dynamic data on chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, c3.js

Hi i am using `c3` chart and here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhuds9wv/) for this i need to show content according to the click button. For example there is four button which is like `7Day` when i do click on it then it will show the last 7 days stats from current date. In this fiddle i put the static data and it is working fine but when i am setting a json and getting it via jquery then it is not working fine.

on click "7 Day" button the chart load again and show data for that i am doing like this

```
$("#days").click(function () {
      var sevenday = JSON.parse($("#sevenday").html());
      var sevenday = JSON.stringify(sevenday[0]);

      console.log(sevenday);
      chart.load({
          columns: [
              ['x',"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"],
              ['Sales', 23000, 19000, 13000, 15000, 13000, 14000, 20000],
              ['Units', 15000, 22000, 21000, 14000, 15000, 20500, 25000]
          ]
      });
      $(".dash-btn-group .btn").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
  });
```

as you can see i am putting value in jquery so it is working fine when i set the data via json and get it in jQuery then it do nothing Rest you can see in fiddle.

```
    <span style="display:none" id="days">['x',"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"]</span>  

 $("#days").click(function () {
  var days = $("#days").html();
      chart.load({
          columns: [
              days,
              ['Sales', 23000, 19000, 13000, 15000, 13000, 14000, 20000],
              ['Units', 15000, 22000, 21000, 14000, 15000, 20500, 25000]
          ]
      });
      $(".dash-btn-group .btn").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
  });
```

You can see xaxis value in not changing when we do click on `7 Day` button

Answer (score 0):

That occurs because when you get the html value you get it as a string and the chart load method expect it as an object. Seems the same when you debug it (on alerts or console.logs, but it's not). There's a simple (but insecure) fix for making JavaScript evaluate the expression and parsing it into JavaScrpt source using eval.
Just replace your load method with:

```
$("#days").click(function () {
  var days = $("#days").html();
      chart.load({
          columns: [
              eval(days),
              ['Sales', 23000, 19000, 13000, 15000, 13000, 14000, 20000],
              ['Units', 15000, 22000, 21000, 14000, 15000, 20500, 25000]
          ]
      });
      $(".dash-btn-group .btn").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
  });
```

And now the chart load method can correctly understand your "days" correctly as it expects.

**Be careful using eval**, it's not a good choice. We are using this here instead of JSON.parse or other JSON methods because days is not a valid JSON in this case. Use it wisely.

[See it working here](https://jsfiddle.net/zhuds9wv/19/)

Comment: first of all thanks for your reply. I have found a solution `var sevenday = JSON.parse($("#sevenday").html());` this is what i am doing while getting data and to show i am doing `sevenday[0]` and it is working fine for me